# How to pass form values of jQuery Credit card validation pawel decowski

Tags: jquery, validation, credit-card

Im using [jQuery Credit Card Validator by Pawel Decowski](http://paweldecowski.github.com/jQuery-CreditCardValidator/) and want to pass the credit card type along with the other credit card detail. His template works fine and I adapted to my website designed. All the values of the form passed but one. **Card Type** - I cannot pass this value to the action because it just only `<li>`, not an input element.

**Javascript**

```
(function() {

  $(function() {
    $('.demo .numbers li').wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return $('#card_number').val($(this).text()).trigger('input');
    });
    $('.vertical.maestro').hide().css({
      opacity: 0
    });
    return $('#card_number').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
      if (!(result.card_type != null)) {
        $('.cards li').removeClass('off');
        $('#card_number').removeClass('valid');
        $('.vertical.maestro').slideUp({
          duration: 200
        }).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 200
        });
        return;
      }
      $('.cards li').addClass('off');
      $('.cards .' + result.card_type.name).removeClass('off');
      if (result.card_type.name === 'maestro') {
        $('.vertical.maestro').slideDown({
          duration: 200
        }).animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, {
          queue: false
        });
      } else {
        $('.vertical.maestro').slideUp({
          duration: 200
        }).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, {
          queue: false,
          duration: 200
        });
      }
      if (result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) {
        return $('#card_number').addClass('valid');
      } else {
        return $('#card_number').removeClass('valid');
      }
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

I have my own live version of fiddle if you guys wanna play with. http://jsfiddle.net/cpR6b/

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/jGESR/

Pseudocode

Add to form tag

```
 <input type='hidden' id='ccType' name='ccType' />
```

Add to JS (assuming that the li classname [.card] will contain one classname which is the card type)

```
 .....
 // check to make sure only one of the card is highlighted)
 if($(".cards li:not('.off')").length == 1){
     $('#ccType').val($(".cards li:not('.off')").attr('class'))
 }

 ...
 if (result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) {
    return $('#card_number').addClass('valid');
 } else {
    return $('#card_number').removeClass('valid');
 }
```

Comment: This relies on the demo code’s HTML structure and not the core library. You can access the card type directly: `if (result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) { $('#ccType').val(result.card_type.name) }`

Answer (score 4):

I would create a hidden form field.  Something like `<input type="hidden" id="cardType" value="" />`.

You could then simply add some jQuery logic in and have it set the value to whatever you wanted.  Something like `$('#cardType').val(result.card_type.name)` would probably work well for you.

Comment: Hi Clay, I've tried to put a hidden input before but no luck. And yet, I don't know which id refers to a card type coz there's no line to tell. :( Have you tried my fiddle?

Comment: No line to tell?  Place the hidden input on your page.  Then place @Clay's jquery line into the pawel code below this line: `$('.cards .' + result.card_type.name).removeClass('off');`

Comment: Hi, I’m the developer of jCCV. This is my preferred solution. The `result.card_type.name` variable holds the actual card type. The current accepted answer is a hack relying on the code of the plugin’s demo page. However, don’t use ethorn10’s suggestion to modify the plugin’s code — there’s no need. Just put Clay’s code inside the `if (result.length_valid && result.luhn_valid) { }` block.